# Is there a Feynman Lectures equivalent in statistics?

Tags: references

I am looking for statistics books that give a good comprehensive overview of the subject, including all its main and mature areas. Something like these equivalents in mathematics:

[Mathematics: Its Contents, Methods and Meaning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486409163)

[Road to Reality](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0679776311)

Or in other words, I'm looking for the [Feynman Lectures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465023827) in statistics.

Does anything like these exist for statistics - preferably at an undergraduate level?

Comment: how much math do you expect to be in this books?

Comment: @rep_ho, what are the available options?

Comment: I don't think there is something really comprehensible, but see other questions where you might find some recommendations eg.: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70545/looking-for-a-good-and-complete-probability-and-statistics-book https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103843/do-you-have-recommendations-for-books-to-self-teach-applied-statistics-at-the-gr https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48347/any-suggestions-for-a-good-undergraduate-introductory-textbook-to-statistics https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/652/best-books-for-an-introduction-to-statistical-data-analysis